# Python validate String containing start_date and end_date for today's date

Tags: python, date, if-statement, time, conditional-statements

I have a string containing `start_date` and `end_date` seperated by `/` like below

```
2017-01-30T12:00-0300/2017-03-30T00:00-0300
```

Here T represents time.

I want to check if this date doesn't exceed today date, do something.

**What I tried-**

```
sale_price_effective_date = current_row['sale_price_effective_date'].split("/")
            start_date = sale_price_effective_date[0]
            end_date = sale_price_effective_date[1]
            print start_date
            print end_date
```

Here `sale_price_effective_date` is the string which contains start_date and end_date.

I would like to do-

```
if (end_date-start_date)>datetime.now():
      //do something
```

Please help. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing only the `end_date` with todays date? `(end_date-start_date)` would give you the difference, and it makes no sense to compare a time delta object with a datetimeobject.

Comment: I mean to say is that start_date and end_date should be in between today's date.

Comment: In between? What do you mean? Do you mean today's date should be in between start and end date?

Comment: yes, exactly  today's date should be in between start and end date?

Comment: For ex if start_date is 2017-01-20 and end_date is 2017-01-22 and as today is 2017-01-23. As today is not between start_date and end_date i will skip that processing.

Comment: Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @MYGz Sorry start_date can be future date. For ex- start_date 2017-1-30 end_date  = 2017-2-30. In that case can I just check if end_date > today's date?

Comment: Yes, then you will have to do only 1 comparison. Check the updated answer. And that is what I predicted initially. Didn't I? !-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime

a = "2017-01-30T12:00-0300/2017-03-30T00:00-0300"
a = map(dateutil.parser.parse, a.split('/'))

if datetime.now(tz=a[1].tzinfo) < a[1]:
    print "Todays date is less than end date"
else:
    print "Todays date is greater than end date"
```

If todays datetime can be less than or equal to end datetime, then put an additional equals sign `=` in comparison like so:

```
datetime.now(tz=a[1].tzinfo) <= a[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
In [1]: from dateutil import parser

In [2]: s = "2017-01-30T12:00-0300/2017-03-30T00:00-0300"

In [3]: start, end = s.split("/")

In [4]: start_date = parser.parse(start)

In [5]: start_date
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 30, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -10800))

In [6]: end_date = parser.parse(end)

In [7]: start_date > end_date
Out[7]: False
```

Edit:

To check if today's date is between start and end you can do:

```
In [19]: from datetime import datetime

In [20]: start_date < datetime.now(tz=start_date.tzinfo) < end_date
Out[20]: False
```

As shown by MYGz.